# Pandas remove number in cell above index column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe which looks like this after some cleaning up.

```
In [363]: treasury_yields_df
Out[363]:
1           1 mo  3 mo  6 mo  1 yr  2 yr  3 yr  5 yr  7 yr 10 yr 20 yr 30 yr
Date
2015-07-01  0.01  0.01  0.13  0.28  0.69  1.08  1.70  2.14  2.43  2.92  3.20
2015-07-02  0.01  0.01  0.10  0.26  0.64  1.01  1.64  2.09  2.40  2.90  3.19
2015-07-06  0.01  0.02  0.09  0.26  0.60  0.95  1.56  2.00  2.30  2.78  3.08
2015-07-07  0.02  0.02  0.08  0.25  0.58  0.96  1.55  1.98  2.27  2.74  3.04
2015-07-08  0.02  0.02  0.08  0.24  0.55  0.91  1.50  1.92  2.22  2.69  2.99
2015-07-09  0.02  0.03  0.08  0.25  0.60  0.95  1.58  2.01  2.32  2.80  3.11
2015-07-10  0.01  0.01  0.09  0.28  0.65  1.04  1.68  2.12  2.42  2.91  3.20
2015-07-13  0.02  0.02  0.10  0.28  0.69  1.06  1.71  2.14  2.44  2.92  3.21
2015-07-14  0.03  0.01  0.10  0.27  0.66  1.03  1.67  2.10  2.41  2.90  3.20
2015-07-15  0.03  0.02  0.11  0.28  0.64  1.00  1.63  2.05  2.36  2.83  3.13
```

I use this dataframe to print with the pandas to_html

```
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th>1</th>
      <th>1 mo</th>
      <th>3 mo</th>
      <th>6 mo</th>
      <th>1 yr</th>
      <th>2 yr</th>
      <th>3 yr</th>
      <th>5 yr</th>
      <th>7 yr</th>
      <th>10 yr</th>
      <th>20 yr</th>
      <th>30 yr</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>2015-07-01</th>
      <td>0.01</td>
      <td>0.01</td>
      <td>0.13</td>
      <td>0.28</td>
      <td>0.69</td>
      <td>1.08</td>
      <td>1.70</td>
      <td>2.14</td>
      <td>2.43</td>
      <td>2.92</td>
      <td>3.20</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>2015-07-02</th>
      <td>0.01</td>
      <td>0.01</td>
      <td>0.10</td>
      <td>0.26</td>
      <td>0.64</td>
      <td>1.01</td>
      <td>1.64</td>
      <td>2.09</td>
      <td>2.40</td>
      <td>2.90</td>
      <td>3.19</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>2015-07-06</th>
      <td>0.01</td>
      <td>0.02</td>
      <td>0.09</td>
      <td>0.26</td>
      <td>0.60</td>
      <td>0.95</td>
      <td>1.56</td>
      <td>2.00</td>
      <td>2.30</td>
      <td>2.78</td>
      <td>3.08</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>2015-07-07</th>
      <td>0.02</td>
      <td>0.02</td>
      <td>0.08</td>
      <td>0.25</td>
      <td>0.58</td>
      <td>0.96</td>
      <td>1.55</td>
      <td>1.98</td>
      <td>2.27</td>
      <td>2.74</td>
      <td>3.04</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>2015-07-08</th>
      <td>0.02</td>
      <td>0.02</td>
      <td>0.08</td>
      <td>0.24</td>
      <td>0.55</td>
      <td>0.91</td>
      <td>1.50</td>
      <td>1.92</td>
      <td>2.22</td>
      <td>2.69</td>
      <td>2.99</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>2015-07-09</th>
      <td>0.02</td>
      <td>0.03</td>
      <td>0.08</td>
      <td>0.25</td>
      <td>0.60</td>
      <td>0.95</td>
      <td>1.58</td>
      <td>2.01</td>
      <td>2.32</td>
      <td>2.80</td>
      <td>3.11</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>2015-07-10</th>
      <td>0.01</td>
      <td>0.01</td>
      <td>0.09</td>
      <td>0.28</td>
      <td>0.65</td>
      <td>1.04</td>
      <td>1.68</td>
      <td>2.12</td>
      <td>2.42</td>
      <td>2.91</td>
      <td>3.20</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>2015-07-13</th>
      <td>0.02</td>
      <td>0.02</td>
      <td>0.10</td>
      <td>0.28</td>
      <td>0.69</td>
      <td>1.06</td>
      <td>1.71</td>
      <td>2.14</td>
      <td>2.44</td>
      <td>2.92</td>
      <td>3.21</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>2015-07-14</th>
      <td>0.03</td>
      <td>0.01</td>
      <td>0.10</td>
      <td>0.27</td>
      <td>0.66</td>
      <td>1.03</td>
      <td>1.67</td>
      <td>2.10</td>
      <td>2.41</td>
      <td>2.90</td>
      <td>3.20</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>2015-07-15</th>
      <td>0.03</td>
      <td>0.02</td>
      <td>0.11</td>
      <td>0.28</td>
      <td>0.64</td>
      <td>1.00</td>
      <td>1.63</td>
      <td>2.05</td>
      <td>2.36</td>
      <td>2.83</td>
      <td>3.13</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

My issue is that I don't want the '1' above the Index column title, and I don't know how to access that value to get rid of it.

And ideally I would quite like the index title in line with the other column titles in the HTML output, though this isn't absolutely essential.

Comment: can you try `treasury_yields_df.columns = treasury_yields_df.columns.values` to see whether the name `1` disappear?

Comment: I think this is the `name` attribute try `df.columns.name = None`

Comment: @JianxunLi yes it did work could you perhaps explain how that works?

Comment: And @EdChum yes that worked too - I didn't realise that there was a columns name value - never came across it yet.

Comment: @BML91 Basically, it reassigns the column names without `.name` property.  it did the same as EdChum's solution, and his code is much concise. :-)

Comment: @EdChum can you add this as an answer so we can close the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The index and columns are type `Index` they have a [`name`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.name.html?highlight=.name#pandas.Index.name) attribute, this is what you are seeing.

To remove the `1` just assign `None` to it:

```
df.columns.name = None
```